# What dimensions should the cabin filter have on a Renault Megane 3 BZAF05 - 1.6 cm - 81 kW?

Tags: renault, cabin-filter, megane

The problem is that all the sellers of the cabin filters provide filters for the BZ0 (I was told that my BZAF05 is BZ0) variant with dimensions of about 260 x 170 mm, while when I tried to measure the space for the filter, I guess that it's about 230 x 150 (it's difficult to get in) and the old filter I got outside was seemingly bent.

If I set it [on this website](https://size.name/en/catalog/filtra-salona?L=230&W=150&H=35), there are no exact dimensions, just similar. Unfortunately, it's not in the user manual either. I am not having the repair manual.

Comment: Have you tried just seeing what the number is listed on your current CAF?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 What is CAF?

Comment: Cabin Air Filter

Comment: Its Filtron K 1300 A. The websites show dimenssions 260 x 149 x 34 mm.

Comment: I"m saying, the part number should be written on the original filter. Did you look at it at all?

Comment: I don't know, I bought the car from someone else. I have seen the filter, which was there, but I was not able to remove it as it was vertical and I cannot squeeze it through the small hole. Now, I have found that they have replaced it probably in the car service with another one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally I consult an online catalogue of the more reputable brands to verify the correctness.

The [Mann catalogue](https://catalog.mann-filter.com) [says](https://catalog.mann-filter.com/EU/ita/catalog/MANN-FILTER%20Katalog%20Europa/Veicoli/AUTOVETTURE%20%2B%20VEICOLI%20COMMERIALI/RENAULT/M%C3%A9gane%20III/1.6%2016V%20K4M%20858%20(T00000000317833)/Filtro%20aria%20cabina/CUK%2026%20005) that the CUK 26 005 with 260 x 150 x 35 is the right one (apparently for the entire Megane 3 series).